# Рисование диаграммы на Silverlight или HTML5

Tags: silverlight, html5

Нужно нарсиовать интерактивную диаграмму БД.

Требования:

- Zoom. Увеличить/уменьшить диаграмму.
- Панорамирование. Возможность перетаскивать диаграмму. Как карту.
- Drag & Drop таблиц.
- Связи между таблицами.

Не хочется вручную рисовать все это дело. Хорошо бы подобрать какую-нибудь бесплатную либу, которая реализовывала бы движок. Можно и платные.

Технологии. Silverlight или HTML5. Что именно - без разницы. Можно реализацию подобной задачи на других технологиях.

Answer (score 1):

Из того, что знаю:
Для HTML5:

- [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/)
- [jQuery Visualize](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/)

Для Silverlight:

- [AnyChart](http://anychart.com/home/)
- [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/)
- [Telerik RadChart](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/chart.aspx)